# Access Sinch PushPayload before `shouldSendPushNotifications`

Tags: ios, sinch

I want to send a push immediately to the other client, regardless of their availability. However the `shouldSendPushNotifications` delegate method is only called ~4 seconds after the call is initialized. Is there a way to access the `pushPayload` of a call from the `SINCall` itself?

Comment: The push callback is delayed because the receiving client have had `setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground:` invoked with YES. So the caller is optimistically waiting for the receiver to acknowledge the caller via the active connection. In case you are using `setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground:YES` (which I assume, is that correct?), push is only used as a fallback and thus delayed. Currently there is no way to programmatically trigger a push callback / retrieve the `pushPayload`.

Comment: In my use case, I would like to send the `pushPayload` regardless of the other client's state. It seems like this is impossible with the current form of the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground:NO and dont startListeningActiveConnecton they you will always have a pushPayload. That is our recomended way of doing it if you want to keep you active usercount down.